# How to find the electric field in a inductor?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-fields, electromagnetic-induction

There's a problem that I didn't understand when I was at school, and it's still unclear. Suppose a simple circuit, an AC constant current source

$I=I_{0}\exp(j\omega t)$ the current is, and an inductor (inductance device) is connected as the load. An inductor is a metal rod. As shown in the following figure. The question is what is the electric field strength E inside the inductor?.
[image]

The inductive impedance of the inductor is $Z=j\omega L+R$, so the voltage on the inductance is $U=IZ$, so according to the circuit theory, the electric field on the inductance is $E=U/l=\frac{IZ}{l}$. Where I is the current of the current source and l is the length of the inductor. However, we can also calculate the electric field of the wire according to the induced electromagnetic field. The formula is
$$
\nabla\times\boldsymbol{E}=-\frac{\partial\boldsymbol{B}}{\partial t}$$
or
$$
\boldsymbol{E}=-\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\boldsymbol{A}=-j\omega\boldsymbol{A}
$$

Where $\boldsymbol{A}$ is the magnetic vector potential and $\omega$ is the AC circular frequency. Which of the following three situations is correct. The electric field strength in the inductance device is,

(A) $E=\frac{IZ}{l}$

(B) $E=-j\omega A$, $A$ is the value of $\boldsymbol{A}$

(C) The summation of (A) and (B)

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid the answer is 'none of the above'. When you 'take off the curl' in the Maxwell equation in your question to get $\mathbf{E}=-\partial\mathbf{A}/\partial t$, you lose a term. There is an extra term $-\nabla V$, and the electric field in the inductor is a sum of these two terms. Firstly there is the $\nabla V$ term, or $\Delta V/l$. But note that $l$ here is the total length of the wire, not the physical length of the inductor, since the wire is all coiled up inside. The second term is the inductive term, which cannot be derived from a potential.

If the wire can be considered a perfect conductor, then these two terms add up to exactly zero! How do I know that? Because a perfect conductor cannot experience an electric field, rather charge always flows to cancel any electric field. In your case, where the inductor has resistance $R$, the electric field is just that needed to maintain the current through the resistance, so it is $IR/l$, where again $l$ is the length of the wire.